# Expanding XFS file system from another device?

Tags: filesystems, storage, xfs

I have two virtual devices on a fedora system. Both are in a raid 5 configuration. No LVM is in place. The system it’s self is installed on one of the devices. That same device is also the one with some un-allocated extra space. Id like the use the space and add it to the file system which is dfw on the other device. Is this is even possible? I was hoping to avoiding rebuilding the system. What are my options?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An XFS filesystem cannot span multiple devices. The only way make use of multiple devices for a traditional filesystem like XFS, EXT[34], etc, is to utilize one of the various mechanisms for creating virtual devices that span multiple physical devices:

- RAID
- LVM
- Etc.

More recent filesystems like BTRFS and ZFS are capable of making use of multiple block devices without additional support.

Answer (score 0):

I think your only option is to split where you store things. So if you store something in array 2 that will fit in the extra space on array 1 then move it there.